# how to calculate mean Average Recall (mAR)?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, metrics

I customized the "https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git" repository to train with my own data set, for object detection, ignoring the segmentation part of the mask. Now, I am evaluating my results, I can calculate the MAP through the function: **compute_ap**, from "https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/utils.py" which returns the "precisions, recalls, overlaps "for each image. I would like to know how can I calculate the mean Average Recall (mAR) using this function: **compute_recall** from "https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/utils.py"?